# Visibility (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: windows-phone-7, save

Sorry if I ask a basic question !

1. Class Customer has got `string Name` and `int Age`
2. In MainPage.xaml.cs I have :

   ObervableCollection < Customer > Customers

In MainPage.xaml :

```
<Listbox x:Name = "ListCustomer" 
          ItemsSources = "{Binding Customers}"/>

<Button x:Name = "Button1" Visibility = "Collapsed"/>
```

How can i set Button1 visibility in MainPage.xaml.cs?

`if(ListCustomer == null)` <-- doesn't have data Button1 is collapsed, if Listbox (or Customer - I don't know)
has got data Button1 is visibled

```
//or if(Customers == null)

{
     Button1.visibility = visibility.visibled
}
```

Where i can put it ?

(in Navigation To, Navigation From, or Page_Load, some where...)

Answer (score 2):

```
Button1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
```

or

```
Button1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

The above code should help you make the button invisible and visible respectively.

It would be best if you could put it in the `Loaded` event handler. This is where you can be sure that all the UI elements are loaded.

Comment: There are other solutions where you can use a boolean variable and bind the visibility of the button to the bool along with a converter to convert true/false into Visibility.Collapsed or Visibility.Visible.